# Theme.MaterialComponents style ruins Firebase AuthUI layout

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, firebaseui, material-components-android

I am writing my first app in kotlin and am using FirebaseAuth & AuthUI for authentication. My login screen works perfectly, and looked like:

[image: this]

Now I am trying to change my AppTheme's parent to "Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar" (from "Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar") but the login screen changed to:

[image: this]

I call the login screen like so:

```
startActivityForResult(
    authUI.createSignInIntentBuilder()
        .setAvailableProviders(providers)
        .build(), 
    RC_SIGN_IN
)
```

I tried to add `.setTheme(R.style.FirebaseUI)` before `.build()`, but it did nothing. I also tried `.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)` just to check what will happen, and it changed the background to dark theme, but the buttons are still purple and no icons. Is it possible to fix this?

Please help me

(also, not very related but maybe the solution will be the same: AuthUI uses Google Smart Lock by default, and I noticed that it's dialog is not affected by the theme I set to the AuthUI. Is it possible to set it to dark mode?)

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

As Himanshu Choudhary suggested in the comments, making a different style for material component, leaving the parent theme as AppCompat and using the material theme in all activities, solves the problem, but it represents problems in layout previews (as they use the application theme). I found a partial solution:
Making a new style like so:

```
    <style name="AppTheme.SignInScreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="materialButtonStyle">?attr/buttonStyle</item>
    </style>
```

and setting it to the the sign-in screen with `.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_SignInScreen)` results to:
[image: this]

I found `?attr/buttonStyle` by looking at the `AppCompatButton` class constructor. Unfortunately, when I set a debug point in that constructor I get different `defStyleAttr` if I set the app theme to `AppCompat`(defStyleAttr=2130903157) or to `MaterialComponents`(defStyleAttr=2130903586). I tried to find what it references to, when using the `AppCompat` app theme, by setting it and looking at the hint, and I found this: `?attr/buttonStyle => ?android:attr/buttonStyle => @style/Widget.Material.Button`, but setting `@android:style/Widget.Material.Button` gives the same result...
Anybody has any idea how to get the icons back? I don't mind overriding the style inflater or even using the actual style id instead of the reference, but I couldn't find any example/explanation of doing those... Please help

Comment: Have you tried changing the theme of the parent layout in the xml layout? I think it might help you!

Comment: The activity that initiates the login screen is my SplashActivity, to which I assign the following theme in the manifest: `<style name="AppTheme.Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_drawable</item>
    </style>` as before the change of my main style. Following your suggestion, I tried setting it also in the xml layout (is that what you meant?), but it's the same :(

Comment: Are you setting the theme to the parent layout in the splash's activity xml layout? If this doesn't work out, try making a different style for material component and let the parent theme as normal one and use the material theme in the activities where it is required.

Comment: My splash activity xml layout looks like that: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Splash"
    tools:context=".ui.SplashActivity"/>` and it doesn't work. I suppose not using the default name "AppTheme" as my actual app theme would fix that, but I was trying to avoid that. I'll try it and tell if works. If you have any other idea please share :)

Comment: It does fix the sign-in screen, but I'm still hoping for a better solution (as I don't like "having to remember" to change each activity's theme, in order to keep a unified app theme).

Comment: I tried the same..It's working for me

Comment: Hi @HimanshuChoudhary, please check edited question

Comment: But why are you extending the name of the new theme from the `AppTheme`. Try making a new name for it.

Comment: It's only naming, what matters is the parent. But anyway, I just tried it too, just in case, and it's the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry its simple, just use one of a bridge theme :

```
Theme.MaterialComponents.Bridge
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge
Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar.Bridge
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge
```

Bridge themes inherit from AppCompat themes, but also define the new Material Components theme attributes for you. If you use a bridge theme, you can start using Material Design components without changing your app theme. (From documentaion)

Have a look : [Get Started - Material design](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started)

What you are facing is the result of default tint the material theme applies to all buttons. You can remove the tint if you want with `app:backgroundTint="none"` and the original background of the button will show.

Comment: Sorry for taking time for coming back to this. Changing to Bridge worked! But as it's a new app, it feels weird to use this "fallback" theme - I don't yet have enough code to say that "I cannot change my theme to inherit from a Material Components theme"... I would like to try your other solution, but where should I put the `app:backgroundTint="none"`? I don't own the problematic layout file, so I can't add it to the button tags in it.