# How to create a custom view inflater and set it to a style resource?

Tags: android, android-styles, layout-inflater, material-components-android

I would like to create a custom view inflater that will inherit from `MaterialComponentsViewInflater` and override the `createButton` function to return a new `AppCompatButton` instead of a new `MaterialButton` (The reason I need this is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65745954/theme-materialcomponents-style-ruins-firebase-authui-layout) problem I'm facing). Creating the class is easy, but I couldn't find how to tell a style resource to use the new class as it's inflater. I thought maybe there is no option at all, but then I saw [this](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/908#issuecomment-621418642) comment. I looked again, but I can't find a single page on the topic. Anyone knows how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a Bridge theme :

```
Theme.MaterialComponents.Bridge
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge
Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar.Bridge
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge
```